# Need help testing data on an array

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, greasemonkey

Im new on GM.
Iv'e run into an problem on an array segment. Here is the code:

```
var A1_rest= '';
var A1reset_go          = false;
var auctiontyp = 0

var myJson              = '{"d":[["","","y","ZAR","1","49517","6458, 8270, 8270, 8270, 7635",null,"1.40","6458","0:13:30","","12","","C","30",null],["y","-00:00","y","ZAR","2","49593","6458, 6458, 6458, 6458, 6458",null,"2.92","6458","0:13:37","","12","","L","12","Ve4mYdrvkkQMKxBH1\/1VMtDTCDQBRspg5jB8jjY08zg="],["","","y","ZAR","3","49058","7456, 9216, 6458, 5153, 7456",null,"194.40","7456","0:00:31","","1100","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","4","49597","2935, 6554",null,"1.22","2935","0:01:16","","12","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","5","49590","4440, 0518, 5343, 2625, 4848",null,"0.95","4440","0:15:58","","5","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","6","49591","4848, 4440, 4440, 0518, 2625",null,"1.81","4848","0:16:05","","12","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","7","49595","6458",null,"5.55","6458","0:04:13","","55","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","8","49596","",null,"2.90","NONE","0:04:35","","29","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","9","49496","6458, 2427, 2427, 7863, 5845",null,"2.56","6458","0:06:07","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","10","49524","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 5845",null,"1.67","6458","0:06:00","","5","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","11","49539","6458, 2427, 7863, 7863, 0764",null,"2.02","6458","0:04:25","","10","","B",null,null]]}'
var jsonObj             = $.parseJSON (myJson);

//--- The JSON should return a 2-D array, named "d".
var arrayOfAuctions     = jsonObj.d;

//--- Loop over each row in the array.
$.each (
    arrayOfAuctions,
    function (rowIndex, singleAuctionData) {

        //--- Print the 7th column.
          console.log ('Row: ' + (parseInt (rowIndex) + 1) + ' Column: 7  Value: ' + singleAuctionData[6]);
  //up to here its fine


  auctiontyp=parseInt (singleAuctionData[4]);
   if (auctiontyp== 1)

     {

   A1_rest=singleAuctionData[16];
       alert(A1_rest);
       alert(singleAuctionData[16]);
        //2 alerts not the same...?
       if (A1_rest != 'null')
         {alert('doing incorrectly');
          A1reset_go=true;
          };
        else
          {alert('success1');
           }
       alert('check5.1');
       alert(A1reset_go);
       if (A1_rest == 'null') and (A1reset_go==true)
         {alert('should also not run but does');
          A1reset_go=false; 
          A1_start=singleAuctionData[8];
         };
         else 
         {alert('success2');
          };
    };
```

my current problem is on :"A1_rest" and "singleAuctionData[16]"

I thought "singleAuctionData[16]" will be a text value of "null" , but it isnt, it is some other value, although, on an alert it gives an output of "null". I'm unsure how to test for it. In this scenario, on the array in the first segment, (which im testing) it should execute "success1" and "success2". On the second segment of the array, if i run the same test , it should only  alert "doing incorrectly" and "success2".
Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.
Ludwig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting a "text value of null", but I think the actual value is just `null`, or nothing, rather than the text `'null'`.

Comment: Thanks. any idea why it consider the test  "if (A1_rest == null) and (A1reset_go==true){}" as true? i guess im using the "and" operator incorrectly.

Comment: I think because when you say if `(A1_rest != 'null')` you are checking against the text string `'null'`, instead of the value `null`. Try removing the quotes.

Comment: ((A1_rest == null) && (A1reset_go==true))   did it.Guess it was "and". dont know GM and java so well...only getting started. was used to turbo pascal... :)